# jQuery UI Sortable can't drag children back into parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/91hjt12h/)

I'm having some trouble getting Sortable to work with these Bootstrap panels. I can drag child panels out of other ones, but not back in. Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="col-xs-11 header-extend-config">
    <div class="panel panel-default header-item">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <i class="fa fa-arrows"></i><h3 class="panel-title">title 1</h3><i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default header-menu">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <i class="fa fa-arrows"></i><h3 class="panel-title">title 2</h3><i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="panel panel-default header-item">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <i class="fa fa-arrows"></i><h3 class="panel-title">title 3</h3><i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default header-item">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <i class="fa fa-arrows"></i><h3 class="panel-title">title 4</h3><i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And the Javascript:

```
$(".panel-body, .header-extend-config").sortable({
    connectWith: ".panel-default, .header-extend-config"
}).disableSelection();
```

Even this [very basic version fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3bcLy0yw/1/) doesn't work, so it can't be Bootstrap causing this issue.

How can I get this to work correctly? (Preferably without some terrible hack)

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I understand correctly, but from what I see you could just add the original `sortable` in the `connectWith` option? http://jsfiddle.net/Lv04w1ub/

Comment: @blgt - wow, I apparently typed `default` instead of `body`. Thanks. Write an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments, there's a typo in the `connectWith` option. It looks like it should use the same selector as the `.sortable`:

```
$(".panel-body, .header-extend-config").sortable({
    connectWith: ".panel-body, .header-extend-config"
}).disableSelection();
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lv04w1ub/